# xampp php access forbidden? How to fix this?

Tags: php, html, xampp, localhost, bootstrap-5

I have index.php that if you log in as a cashier you would go to the cashier.php
Cashier Page:
[image: ![cashier page]

and when you login as an you can go between dashboard.php or products.php

[image: Dashboard Page]

But when I go to the product page I always have this error
Product Page:
[image: product Page]

Comment: Your screenshot is cutting off the URL that's causing the problem. It seems that the `products.php` is working okay, but it's trying to load some other resource (an image?) that's failing. The issue is at line 159 of the HTML output generated by `products.php` (which is very unlikely to be at line 159 of `products.php` itself).

Comment: I see where's my problem now, its the <img src"...">